# How can I truncate the multiline text from the database? (html/css/php)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, sql

How can I truncate the data, which I fetch from my MySQL database?

My html code:

```html
<div class="content">
    <h3 class="title"><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
    <p class="main" id="main"><?php echo $content; ?></p>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i> Artikel lesen</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Post a full code. What are `$title` and `$content`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to truncate the value of a column, you can do that directly using the `left` or `right` function. You need to pass the amount of characters you want to get either from left or right respectively

Eg: left()

```
select left('left function',4) as content;

output: left
```

Eg: right()

```
select right('left function', 4) as content;

output: tion
```

if `content` is your column  then you can use the following snippet:

```
select left(content,10) as content from <YourTableName>;
```