# How can I truncate text as the page gets smaller with css?

Tags: html, css, truncate

How can I truncate text as the page gets smaller with CSS?

Currently, as the page gets smaller, the text goes under the elements and isn't truncated.

```html
<div class="flex-parent has-child">

  <div class="flex-child long-and-truncated-with-child-corrected">
       <div class="logo">logo </div>
    <div>
      <h2> This is a long string that is OK to truncate please and thank you</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="flex-child short-and-fixed">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

```sass
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 30px 0;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.short-and-fixed {
  white-space: nowrap;
  > div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: lightgreen;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

.long-and-truncated-with-child-corrected {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0; /* or some value */
  h2 {
      display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
}

body {
  padding: 40px;
}
```

or try [codepen](https://codepen.io/tomo1127/pen/NWBBzVZ?editors=1100)

If users access this on their laptops or tablets, they will be able to see the whole text(`This is a long string that is OK to truncate please and thank you`).

However, they shouldn't see the text when they use their phones since there is not enough space for it.

Also, the text(`This is a long string that is OK to truncate please and thank you`) is dynamic so there will be the time when text is shorter or longer so I don't want to set `max-width` or `width`.

#### Attempts

I found multiple links doing similar things but didn't apply to my case.

[Truncate text with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43999129/truncate-text-with-css)

[How can I truncate centered text by letter with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68197689/how-can-i-truncate-centered-text-by-letter-with-css)

[How can I truncate the multiline text from the database? (html/css/php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64416730/how-can-i-truncate-the-multiline-text-from-the-database-html-css-php)

Comment: You appear to be trying to use some sort of CSS preprocessor syntax. Are you using a preprocessor like Sass or is this vanilla CSS?

Comment: @Phil So my code is actually written in reactjs and styled-components, but I found the link trying to do what I like to do so I just used some of their code.